Flutter Error after migrating project to latest flutter
Launching lib\main.dart on Pixel 4 XL in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/rounded_loading_button-2.1.0/lib/rounded_loading_button.dart:197:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'onSurface'.
onSurface: widget.disabledColor,
^^^^^^^^^
/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/elevated_button.dart:151:22: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
static ButtonStyle styleFrom({
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/layout_grid.dart:212:20: Error: Inferred type argument 'AutoPlacement' doesn't conform to the bound 'Enum?' of the type variable 'T' on 'EnumProperty'.

'AutoPlacement' is from 'package:flutter_layout_grid/src/widgets/layout_grid.dart' ('/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/layout_grid.dart').
'Enum' is from 'dart:core'.
Try specifying type arguments explicitly so that they conform to the bounds.
properties.add(EnumProperty('autoPlacement', autoPlacement));
^
/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2258:20: Context: This is the type variable whose bound isn't conformed to.
class EnumProperty<T extends Enum?> extends DiagnosticsProperty {
^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:82:55: Error: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'.
'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
final AbstractNode? targetParent = renderObject.parent;
^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:83:58: Error: The method 'markNeedsPlacement' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsPlacement'.
if (targetParent is RenderLayoutGrid) targetParent.markNeedsPlacement();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:84:54: Error: The method 'markNeedsLayout' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsLayout'.
if (targetParent is RenderObject) targetParent.markNeedsLayout();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:132:55: Error: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'.
'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
final AbstractNode? targetParent = renderObject.parent;
^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:133:58: Error: The method 'markNeedsPlacement' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsPlacement'.
if (targetParent is RenderLayoutGrid) targetParent.markNeedsPlacement();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:134:54: Error: The method 'markNeedsLayout' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsLayout'.
if (targetParent is RenderObject) targetParent.markNeedsLayout();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:186:20: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
'TapDragDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart').
onTapDown: onTapDown,
^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:190:24: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapUpDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpDetails)?'.
'TapUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
'TapDragUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart').
onSingleTapUp: onSingleTapUp,
^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:195:26: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
'TapDragDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart').
onDoubleTapDown: onDoubleTapDown,
^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:196:31: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragStartDetails)?'.
'DragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
'TapDragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart').
onDragSelectionStart: onDragSelectionStart,
^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:197:32: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDetails, DragUpdateDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpdateDetails)?'.
'DragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
'DragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
'TapDragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart').
onDragSelectionUpdate: onDragSelectionUpdate,
^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:198:29: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragEndDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragEndDetails)?'.
'DragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
'TapDragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart' ('/D:/softwares/flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap_and_drag.dart').
onDragSelectionEnd: onDragSelectionEnd,
^
/C:/Users/PMLS/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/handle_overlay.dart:60:40: Error: Member not found: 'fadeDuration'.
duration: TextSelectionOverlay.fadeDuration, vsync: this);
^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'D:\softwares\flutter_sdk\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1419

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.



Process 'command 'D:\softwares\flutter_sdk\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
enter image description here
I was trying to migrate project. So, I had had upgraded my flutter sdk and then i had done changes to my project and v2 version embedding. but after doing so much work i stucked here. if anyone can help that will be aprreciated. Thanks

I am experiencing the same problem after upgrading to Flutter 3.24. Seems Rounded_Loading_Button is incompatible with the newest version. Does anyone know of a workaround other than removing Rounded_Loading_Button package?

Hi Dan!  I have solved this problem by removing the rounded loading button. Cause it was incompatible. And replaced it with a new package. If you have further query contact maali22786@gmail.com

Thanks. I upgraded to Rounded Loaded Button 2 package that does not have any conflicts with the latest Flutter version

@Dan12314 can you give me the link to Rounded Loaded Button 2 package?
